# How to make php cURL case sensitive

Tags: php, curl, case-sensitive

I am trying to get data from Instagram link as JSON and get some objects , but when i use cURL i get an empty JSON .

I believe the problem is caused by the cURL converting url to lowercase

`https://www.instagram.com/p/CEwYF4FhXpz/?__a=1`

Is not equivalent to

`https://www.instagram.com/p/cewyf4fhxpz/?__a=1`

So my question is how can i force PHP CURL to be case sensitive

**My code**

```
$test_URL="https://www.instagram.com/p/CEwYF4FhXpz/?__a=1";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $test_URL);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $obj = json_decode($result);

    return $obj;
```

Comment: Why would case sensitivity be an issue?

Comment: enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and post the verbose log

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this.

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
```

Comment: Okay after some research it must be case insensitive. You can try your luck with the facebook api.

Answer (score -2):

> https://www.instagram.com/p/CEwYF4FhXpz/?__a=1

> Is not equivalent to

> https://www.instagram.com/p/cewyf4fhxpz/?__a=1

that part is correct...

> I believe the problem is caused by the cURL converting url to lowercase

that's bullshit. here's the request your code is sending, except i've replaced  `https://www.instagram.com` with `http://localhost:9999`, and running a netcat server on localhost port 9999:

```
$ nc -l 9999
GET /p/CEwYF4FhXpz/?__a=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
Accept: */*
```

also you can check the url you're sending yourself with CURLOPT_VERBOSE,

```
$stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */
rewind($stderrh); 
$stderr=stream_get_contents($stderrh);
fclose($stderrh);
echo $stderr;
```

also when running your code here, it works fine. so either you're being IP-blocked, or the server you're running PHP on has blocked curl, check the VERBOSE log and you might get a clue